# workers skip commands using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def kData(self, data, auth_token, apifolder, additional_parameter_key=None, additional_parameter_value=None):
try:
    ...
    if responsefirst.ok:
        print ("num of records to import is {0}".format(num_of_records))
        print ("num of pages to import is {0}".format(num_of_pages))
        pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
        datarALL = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata, page, data, apifolder, additional)) for page in pages]
            for data in as_completed(futh):
                datarALL.extend(data.result())
        print ("Finished generateing data.")
        return datarALL
    else:
        print (responsefirst)
        return None
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    print (str(e))

def getdata(self, page, data, apifolder, additional):
    tries = 10
    ...
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            value_offset = page * value_limit
            datarALL = []
            url = 'http://...offset={0}&limit={1}{3}'.format(
                value_offset, value_limit, apifolder, additional)
            print ("{3} Generate page: #{0} run #{1} with URL: {2}".format(page, n, url,str(datetime.now())))
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
            responsedata.raise_for_status()
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
                        break

        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
            if n == tries - 1:
                print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
                print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and exit the process.

    print ("{2} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now())))
    return datarALL
```

This code gets pages from API using threads and paging. Each page has 10 times to try to get the data. If failed the whole program is terminated.
I have only 4 workers so only 4 pages can be fetched at the same time..

However when I check the prints I see:

```
num of records to import is 20353
num of pages to import is 21
2018-09-06 10:20:27.088819 Generate page: #0 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=0&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:20:27.090569 Generate page: #1 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=1000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:20:27.093557 Generate page: #2 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=2000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:20:27.093977 Generate page: #3 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=3000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:02.996702 page 0 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:21:02.997510 Generate page: #4 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=4000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:07.396665 page 3 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:21:07.405115 Generate page: #5 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=5000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:09.810959 page 2 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:21:09.811804 Generate page: #6 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=6000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:12.139825 page 1 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:21:12.140538 Generate page: #7 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=7000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:58.481575 page 4 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:21:58.511109 Generate page: #8 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=8000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:58.649614 Generate page: #9 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=9000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:21:58.763254 Generate page: #10 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=10000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:22:37.051543 page 10 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:22:37.062028 Generate page: #11 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=11000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:22:51.951209 page 9 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:22:52.127068 Generate page: #12 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=12000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:22:58.827537 page 8 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:22:58.828348 Generate page: #13 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=13000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:23:17.051456 page 11 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:23:17.052026 Generate page: #14 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=14000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:23:33.567374 page 12 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:23:33.590438 Generate page: #15 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=15000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:23:49.212171 page 13 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:23:49.212833 Generate page: #16 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=16000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:23:49.888996 Generate page: #17 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=17000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:24:13.566604 page 15 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:24:13.567329 Generate page: #18 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=18000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:24:29.247905 page 16 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:24:29.470544 Generate page: #19 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=19000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:24:47.225006 page 17 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-06 10:24:47.225765 Generate page: #20 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=20000&limit=1000
2018-09-06 10:25:00.036472 page 20 finished. Length is 353
2018-09-06 10:25:14.520772 page 19 finished. Length is 1000
```

This log doesn't make scene pages #5,#6 never printed the finish message. they also did not retry because the log doesn't show `run #1` for them. 
This sometimes happens and when it goes some threads are stuck (I see it on `htop`) eventually the script is being Killed.

Something is wrong with the code and I can't figure out what & why...

Comment: The thread may get stuck in requests.get. Try some timeout value and retry if request timeouts.

Comment: @AjaySrivastava How can it stuck? and if it stuck how can it moved to the next page? Can you show how to force retry?

Comment: It might be the case that only one thread is working and rest of the threads are stuck. You can verify this by printing thread name in prints. I will write the example code of retry in answer.

Comment: @AjaySrivastava how can I write the thread names? I tried to write the worker number but I don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

You can write a different method for fetching data.

```
def getDataWithRetry(self, url, data, timeoutValue):
    responsedata = None
    retry = None
    try:
        responsedata = requests.get(url, timeout=timeoutValue, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
        retry = False
    except (requests.Timeout):
        retry = True

    return (retry, responsedata)
```

Call this method from getdata in loop till retry is False. You can also limit the retries by keeping a loop counter.

For printing name of thread.

```
import threading
print(threading.current_thread().getName())
```

**Reply after comment -**

Modify requests.get call as -

```
responsedata = requests.get(url, timeout=120, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
```

and except statement as -

```
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.Timeout, ConnectionResetError) as e:
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following this.. My code has a loop... won't it simply go to the next iteration?

Comment: I overlooked that. You can add timeout in requests.get call and catch requests.Timeout for retry.

Comment: I have modified answer in reply to your comment.

Comment: what is the difference between requests.Timeout and requests.exceptions.Timeout ?

Comment: after applying your suggestion the issue still occur... This is not related to timeout... Log: `2018-09-06 12:42:05.772028 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #3 run #0 
2018-09-06 12:43:13.761325 Thread: Thread-4 page 3 finished. 2018-09-06 12:43:13.762230 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #7 
2018-09-06 12:43:58.374778 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #10 run #0`  as you can see `thread 4` did not print the finish message for `page #7`

Comment: You can try catching all the exception in getdata and see if the problem still persists.